# get RadioButtonList selected value in gridview via foreach

Tags: asp.net

I have this code:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Comment")
{
    SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(ClsPublic.GetConnectionString());
    SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblImages SET fComment = @fComment WHERE (fId=@fId)", scn);

    string mytext = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GVPictures.Rows)
    {
        mytext = ((RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("RBComment")).SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fComment", mytext);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fId", e.CommandArgument);
    scn.Open();
    scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    scn.Close();
}
```

However, this code returns the value of last row and not my selected row. What can I do?
How can I get selected row value ?

Answer (score 0):

'((RadioButtonList)e.SelectedRow.FindControl("RBComment")).SelectedValue.Text;
OR
((RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("RBComment")).SelectedValue.Text;'